# amd driver catalyst 13.1 problem 15.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, ati, fglrx

I got a problem installing amd drivers. Here is the fglrx-install.log:

```
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  
/lib/modules/3.19.0-15-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.
```

I've tried to update/install headers with `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
 but it says I've got newest version.

Comment: Instead of editting would You mind sharing the solution.....?